# How to check box within PoweShell Script

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to run this Python EXE application and wanted get the ADD PYTHON 3.6 TO PATH ticked within my PowerShell Script for multiple users on a domain

I've currently following, which works fine without giving me a pop-up box.

$Arguments = @(
"/S"
"/V/qn"
)
Start-Process -FilePath “\FILE-LOCATION\python-3.6.4-amd64.exe” -ArgumentList $Arguments -Wait -NoNewWindow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA1dZ.png)

I will like to install the Python 3.6.4 (64 Bit) with Pygame 1.9.3 (64 Version) together

Comment: Hi! How about adding to the path directly using PowerShell: like `$env:Path += ';C:\<pathToInstallation>'?